# iOS Developer Contracts Missing

Tags: app-store-connect

After watching the WWDC 13' announcement of iOS 7 I wanted to download and install the beta release of the new OS using my paid developer account. I logged on to iTunesConnect and was greeted with a message telling me I would need to review and agree to the new Developer Agreement and Paid Applications agreement before I can make any app updates. Additionally, my subscription expires on JULY 19th (about 39 days from now). I don't want to (and can't afford to) renew it until it's actually close to expiring.

For whatever reason, I cannot seem to find where I'm supposed to go to can accept the updated documents. The "Contracts, Tax and Billing" section only gives me the option to view the current documents in place, not renew or review the revised copies. Additionally, the "Member Center" simply wines at me to renew my subscription, not telling me where the agreement documents are.

If anyone else is having this issue, please let me know how you got through it. I've contacted Apple Support and I'll post what I hear from them.

Comment: same problem here.. wanted to prepare an update, but it keeps complaining about some agreements that I can't find anywhere to sign them.

Comment: Similar problem here. This is probably being discussed somewhere (else).

Comment: This is silly, but I got past it by clicking on the Profiles page (the only place you can get to) and then making some random moves from there. Not only is this not rocket science, but sometimes it's not science at all.

On the other hand, I'm pretty sure I had a different problem then you. In mine, the /contracts URL would redirect me back to login (endless loop).

Comment: @Yar Your comment might make not only a good answer, but a correct answer.

Comment: It appears to have been a temporary glitch. After experiencing a problem similar to the OP's, it resolved itself today - the Contracts & Banking module on itunesconnect.com is accessible again. Seems like Apple is in the process of revamping their sites, with features breaking intermittently.

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple has a support department to help paid developers, have you made use of that support?

- https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

From your description, it's likely you are not making a mistake and the problem is on the server end, but it could also be something where a warning is being dismissed as whining and the information is there for you to assemble and act on.